# Algorithm to match Rubik snake shape

Tags: java, algorithm, rotation

I am trying to implement a Rubik snake simulation, if I have a model that is formed from the string `000000020000200000020000` 24 block which each character means rotation angle for the opposite block, if a block rotated it rotates all blocks next to it.

```
if 0 = no rotation
1 = 90
2 = 180
3 = 270
```

how to check if the same shape is formed by different steps `200002000000020000200000`

I implement in Java.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @bkis I tried in linear algebra to match the center points for each block but it wasn't accurate or may be my implementation was not correct

Answer (score 1):

Call snake1 and snake2 your two snakes.

Imagine that snake1 and snake2 form the same shape. Think about the first block of snake1. This block should align with one of the blocks from snake2 in order for the two shapes to coincide. With which block of snake2 does the first block of snake1 align?

This question gives the beginning of an algorithm. If the first block of snake1 is blue, then loop through all the blue blocks of snake2 one after the other, and assume the first block of snake1 aligns with this block of snake2. There are two orientations the first block of snake1 might be in compared to this block of snake2; you'll have to loop through these two possible orientations.

Once you've chosen a block of snake2 and an orientation, call `(0,0,0)` the position of the first block of snake1 in space, and loop through all the blocks of snake1, and store their position by writing `blue` or `black` in an array representing all the possible positions in 3d space. All cells of the array which do not contain a block are marked `empty`.

Do the same in a second array for the blocks of snake2.

The two snakes represent the same shape if and only if the two arrays represent the same shape.

PS: Since the blocks are prisms and not cubes, if a cell in the array represent a cube, then you need to be a bit more explicit than just `blue`/`black`/`empty` in the description of what a cell contains. So you need to either:

- find a cleverer way to represent space than a simple 3d array; or
- find good descriptions of the possible contents of a cell (something like "half-black half-blue in what orientation").